# Xamarin.iOS, Xcode 8.0, iOS 10.0 Update & iPod Touch Test Device

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios

As of Saturday, September 18th - my MacBook Pro laptop is running Xcode 8.0;

A previously built, and published Xamarin.IOS app with a Deployment Target 9.3 - now has a Deployment Target of 10.0, and the project is being enhanced;

If the app is run, with feature updates - all is OK in the Xamarin iOS iPhoneSimulator(s), and the app works correctly;

However, on an iPod Touch test device running iOS 10.0.1 (14A403) - the app does not display an initial TableViewController;

The Launch Screen, and a sign on page load correctly on the iPod Touch, running iOS 10.0.1 - the issue is the initial TableViewContoller not showing;

Any insight, advice is appreciated;

Comment: More details: if running in debug, targeting an iPod Touch with iOS 10 - the following error occurs: ERROR Error executing SQLite command: 'unable to open database file'.
ERROR Object reference not set to an instance of an object

The above error dos not occur if targeting the iOS Simulator;

Comment: Issue resolved:   use local data source, and app can be used in local-only data mode; update settings to indicate a local data source should be used & register the local data provider;

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved:   use local data source, and app can be used in local-only data mode; update settings to indicate a local data source should be used & register the local data provider;